# IconStyle hotspot not working as expected in tilt mode on Google Earth desktop

Tags: kml, google-earth

While creating a kml file, I'm encountering this annoying problem:

A placemark with icon hotspot set to the center is being placed just above the track path, instead of centered on it, when the view is being *tilted*.
This happens in Google Earth desktop for Windows [7.1.5.1557], while it is working correctly in Earth for Android, see here:

Screenshot Google Earth desktop Win (wrong hotspot when view is tilted):

[image: Screenshot Google Earth desktop Win]

Screenshot Google Earth Android (correct hotspot when view is tilted):

[image: Screenshot Google Earth Android]

The iconStyle is defined as follows:

```
<IconStyle>
<Icon><href>wp_icon.png</href></Icon>
<scale>0.7</scale>
<hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction " yunits="fraction" />
</IconStyle>
```

When I add the following, I can make it work like it should in Earth desktop, but then in Earth Android the icons are misplaced even more:

```
<heading>180</heading>
<gx:headingMode>screenUp</gx:headingMode>
```

I tried different combinations with heading values and

```
<gx:headingMode>screenUp</gx:headingMode>
<gx:headingMode>northUp</gx:headingMode>
<gx:headingMode>worldNorth</gx:headingMode>
```

but with no success to get the icons being displayed correctly in both versions of Earth (Win/Android).

Since I do not know a place to post bugs (https://code.google.com/p/earth-issues/ has been closed), I hope somebody from the Earth team will look into this, if nobody else comes up with a solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hotspot is correctly implemented with top-down view in mind, but there are a number of rendering bugs when you start tilting. As the tilt towards the horizon the icon starts to appear over above the point where it is placed, which is the behavior you are seeing. This particular bug was reported in the private google earth beta forum. The icon size also becomes smaller until they nearly completely appear at a 90 degree angle.

The Android app is newer than the Windows desktop app so apparently it compensates for the tilt when drawing the icons. It's a bug in the desktop client so any attempt to fix it in the desktop will most likely break it in the Android client as you've seen.

Surprised `<gx:headingMode>` does anything since that is not a documented [Google Earth extension](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kml-extension-namespace-and-the-gx-prefix). This also does not appear in the most current [XML schema](http://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd). Careful about using undocumented extensions which may or may not work on a given client.

With earth-issues closed you can post problems to the [Google Earth forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/maps/google-earth). For bugs you will be advised to submit feedback via the Help menu in Google Earth for the GE team to get them.

Comment: Thanks for the precise info. So I guess, I will have to keep the definition the standard way and hope for a fix in the future. Extremely surprised, that such an obvious and probably easy to solve bug is still present in such a 'grown up' piece of software.